# Backup task/plugin for hudson not working - how do I fix it?

Tags: hudson

I installed the backup plugin for hudson and when a backup is requested it attempts to shutdown hudson.  It seems to hang in that state.

What could be causing this?

It is running on Windows 7 as a service.

the real issue I want to solve though is how to back up my hudson configurations.  (hudson, plugins, jobs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145050/is-there-an-automated-way-to-backup-hudson-ci-files/1162173#1162173) to a similar question. I like his robocopy approach. Right now I am implementing his approach as a Hudson job.

The job uses the [filesystem-scm-plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/File+System+SCM) and copies the configuration every time the xml-files change. Since  the harddrive is backed up anyway, I am only interested in a change history for the job configurations. If you do it this way, remember, to put the workspace for your backup job, outside usual Hudson directories, otherwise it will be triggered unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that answer before - when looking for a solution to my problem.  However, I'd prefer to use the plugin as I am not familiar with robocopy and frankly I prefer to stop the increase of disparate tools in my dev process...   +1 for the filesystem-scm-plugin - that might do the trick for me.

Comment: On second thought - after reading about robocopy, it looks like that is a great alternative.  I am still hoping that the backup plugin is improved, but until then I have workaround(s).

Comment: Robocopy is a Microsoft tool, which is very powerful. However, that makes it dangerous too (e.g. it can delete files). It is shipped with the newer Server OSs ans was available in the resource kits for the older ones. Not sure if it is on board for Win 7 though. I use it instead of a standard copy, because it keeps going on even, if it has an error copying a file. Be sure to check what the error code means. It is not the traditional everything-except-0-is-bad philosophy.