# Is there a way to keep Hudson / Jenkins configuration files in source control?

Tags: version-control, hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Hudson / Jenkins and was wondering if there is a way to check in Hudson's configuration files to source control.

Ideally I want to be able to click some button in the UI that says 'save configuration' and have the Hudson configuration files checked in to source control.

Comment: Or you can store those information in a Git repo on demand: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21020885/6309)

Comment: See also: [Can I store Jenkins configuration in the project repo (like Travis)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28291313/509706)

Comment: Check: [HUDSON_HOME directory](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson) for structure of the Jenkins files.

Comment: @kenorb Links are dead.

Comment: See also [SE DevOps: How do you back up Jenkins jobs & master configs?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/21/24991).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## Most helpful Answer

There is a plugin called [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration/).

---

## Original Answer

Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079383/backup-task-plugin-for-hudson-not-working-how-do-i-fix-it/2087082#2087082) to a similar question. The basic idea is to use the [filesystem-scm-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/File+System+SCM) to detect changes to the xml-files. Your second part would be committing the changes to SVN.

**EDIT:** If you find a way to determine the user for a change, let us know.

**EDIT 2011-01-10** Meanwhile there is a new plugin: [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration/). Currently it only works with subversion and git, but support for more repositories is planned. I am using it since version 0.0.3 and it worked good so far.

Comment: Thanks for the SCM Sync configuration plugin. Does exactly what its supposed to!

Comment: Has this changed name? I don't see it listed with all the other available plugins here: http://myjenkinshost:jenkins/pluginManager/available

Comment: I beg to differ: the plugin has some major weaknesses if you use git and operate in a complex environment:
'If you use Git then you should use SSH key with default name. It's "id_rsa". SCM Sync does not have option to specify ssh key path. SCM Sync uses .ssh/id_rsa from home directory of the jenkins process owner.' from [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScmSyncConfig+Troubleshootings]

Comment: The SCM Sync Configuration plugin is incompatible with the Subversion plugin >=2.0 (per https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21640).

Comment: SCM Sync Plugin has too much issues to be used with SVN (subversion 2 is not supported so credentials can not be passed, job renaming is not working, exceptions and empty Jenkins page after plugin installation)

Comment: I won't recommend using this particular plugin , post installation jenkins didn't come up. There seems to be lots of bugs in this plugin and it doesn't gets upgrade / fixes too frequently. Avoid "SCM Sync configuration plugin"

Comment: @vikramvi, what is the alternative you propose?

Comment: @IgorRodriguez As jenkins job doesn't undergo frequent changes compared to project code; I'm doing committing changes manually to github.

Comment: “**The SCM Sync plugin is deprecated**”

Answer (score 38):

Note that Vogella has a recent (January 2014, compared to the OP's question January 2010) and different take on this.
Consider that the [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration/) can generate *a lot of* commits.
So, instead of relying on a plugin and an automated process, he manages the same feature manually:

### [Storing the Job information of Jenkins in Git](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/01/07/storing-the-job-information-of-jenkins-in-git/)

> I found the amount of commits a bit overwhelming, so I decided to control the commits manually and to save only the Job information and not the Jenkins configuration.
> For this switch into your Jenkins jobs directory (Ubuntu: `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs`) and perform the “`git init`” command.

> I created the following `.gitignore` file to store only the Git jobs information:

```
builds/
workspace/
lastStable
lastSuccessful
nextBuildNumber
modules/
*.log
```

> Now you can add and commit changes at your own will.
> And if you add another remote to your Git repository you can push your configuration to another server.

[Alberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413020/alberto) actually recommend to add as well (in `$JENKINS_HOME`):

- jenkins own config (`config.xml`),
- the jenkins plugins configs (`hudson*.xml`) and
- the users configs (`users/*/config.xml`)

Comment: Wouldn't storing the user configs expose the plaintext API tokens in their `config.xml`?

Comment: @Boon I don't know actually, since I did not have to use API token recently. That could be a good question on its own for you to ask.

Comment: After some research, turns out that the API tokens are encrypted in the XML, so this would not pose a security risk.

Answer (score 22):

To manually manage your configuration with Git, the following .gitignore file may be helpful.

```
# Miscellaneous Hudson litter
*.log
*.tmp
*.old
*.bak
*.jar
*.json

# Generated Hudson state
/.owner
/secret.key
/queue.xml
/fingerprints/
/shelvedProjects/
/updates/

# Tools that Hudson manages
/tools/

# Extracted plugins
/plugins/*/

# Job state
builds/
workspace/
lastStable
lastSuccessful
nextBuildNumber
```

See [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/780105) and [this blog post](https://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/store-hudson-configuration-in-git/) for more details.

Comment: what about the caches directory, is there a reason not to ignore that?

Answer (score 14):

There is a new [SCM Sync Configuration plug-in](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration/) which does exactly what you are looking for.

> SCM Sync Configuration Hudson plugin
> is aimed at 2 main features :
>
> - Keep sync'ed your config.xml (and other ressources) hudson files with a
>   SCM repository
> - Track changes (and author) made on every file with commit messages

I haven't actually tried this yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: I'd be interested in a working configuration of the SCM Sync Configuration plug-in with Git, I tried several configurations and I simply couldn't make it work (and the error messages in the logs were unhelpful at best).

Comment: The [SCM Sync Configuration plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scm-sync-configuration/) is deprecated: "_In general, this means that this plugin is either obsolete, no longer being developed, or may no longer work._".

Answer (score 9):

You can find configuration files in [Jenkins home folder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins`).

To keep them in VCS, first login as Jenkins (`sudo su - jenkins`) and create its git credentials:

```
git config --global user.name "Jenkins"
git config --global user.email "jenkins@example.com"
```

Then initialize, add and commit the basic files such as:

```
git init
git add config.xml jobs/ .gitconfig
git commit -m'Adds Jenkins config files' -a
```

also consider creating `.gitignore` with the following files to ignore (customize as needed):

```
# Git untracked files to ignore.

# Cache.
.cache/

# Fingerprint records.
fingerprints/

# Working directories.
workspace/

# Secret files.
secrets/
secret.*
*.enc
*.key
users/
id_rsa

# Plugins.
plugins/

# State files.
*.state

# Job state files.
builds/
lastStable
lastSuccessful
nextBuildNumber

# Updates.
updates/

# Hidden files.
.*
# Except git config files.
!.git*
!.ssh/

# User content.
userContent/

# Log files.
logs/
*.log

# Miscellaneous litter
*.tmp
*.old
*.bak
*.jar
*.json
*.lastExecVersion
```

Then add it: `git add .gitignore`.

When done, you can add job config files, e.g.

```
shopt -s globstar
git add **/config.xml
git commit -m'Added job config files' -a
```

Finally add and commit any other files if needed, then push it to the remote repository where you want to keep the config files.

---

When Jenkins files are updated, you need to reload them (*Reload Configuration from Disk*) or run `reload-configuration` from Jenkins CLI.

Comment: Why are the Site-wide configurations excluded? I see that other answers do include them.

Comment: @kenorb I'd exclude it again. A comment line above `*.xml` doesn't change the rule and git ignores **all** xml files including `config.xml` from `jobs` directory, `git status` hereupon silently ignores any _new_ project.

Comment: I cannot ignore `plugins/` otherwise the Jenkins server doesn't start after a fresh clone of my Jenkins repo: `SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading global config .. com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy`. The only way to successful launch Jenkins from a fresh cloned repo was to version control the `plugins/` too.. but that directory is humongous and full of binary files! For the same reason, I was unable to have `*.jar` in `.gitignore` as well.

Answer (score 6):

A more accurate `.gitignore`, inspired by the reply from [nepa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869377/nepa):

```
*
!.gitignore
!/jobs/
!/jobs/*/
/jobs/*/*
!/jobs/*/config.xml
!/users/
!/users/*/
/users/*/*
!/users/*/config.xml
!/*.xml
```

It ignores everything except for `.xml` config files and `.gitignore` itself.
(the difference to [nepa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869377/nepa)'s `.gitignore` is that it doesn't "unignore" all top-level directories (`!*/`) like `logs/`, `cache/`, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

The way I prefer is to exclude everything in the Jenkins home folder *except* the configuration files you really want to be in your VCS. Here is the `.gitignore` file I use:

```
*
!.gitignore
!/jobs/*/*.xml
!/*.xml
!/users/*/config.xml
!*/
```

This ignores everything (`*`) except (`!`) `.gitignore` itself, the jobs/projects, the plugin and other important and user configuration files.

It's also worth considering to include the `plugins` folder. Annoyingly updated plugins should be included...

Basically this solution makes it easier for future Jenkins/Hudson updates because new files aren't automatically in scope. You just get on the screeen what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from Mark (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066654/142207) should work for SVN and Git (although Git configuration did not work for me).

But if you need it to work with Mercurial repo, create a job with following script:

```
hg remove -A || true
hg add ../../config.xml
hg add ../../*/config.xml
if [ ! -z "`hg status -admrn`" ]; then
    hg commit -m "Scheduled commit" -u fill_in_the@blank.com
    hg push
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I've [written a plugin](https://github.com/manahl/recipebuilder) that lets you check your Jenkins instructions into source control. Just add a `.jenkins.yml` file with the contents:

```
script:
    - make
    - make test
```

and Jenkins will do it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I checked in hudson entirely, you could use this as a starting point https://github.com/morkeleb/continuous-delivery-with-hudson

There are benefits to keeping entire hudson in git. All config changes are logged and you can test the testup quite easily on one machine and then update the other machine(s) using git pull.

We used this as a boilerplate for our hudson continuous delivery setup at work.

Regards
Morten