# storing Hudson build scripts in a git repo

Tags: git, hudson

I'm looking to version and backup the task configurations and scripts in hudson now that we have more than one person editing them and this seems like a great job for git. I'll bet someone already has a plugin or something that will do this automagically. If not then would it work and or be ellegant to just run `git init` in the hudson config dir?

Comment: needs to deal with permissions: it would be great if the logged in user's name was on each change

Comment: You can also edit your question if you want to add additional information. No need to comment on your own question.

Comment: Have you looked at the Backup and Job Config History plugins? They don't do the git part, but at least seem to store some info about changes made and by whom.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087142/is-there-a-way-to-keep-hudson-configuration-files-in-source-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new plugin: [SCM Sync configuration plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin). So far it only works with subversion, but the author wants to add other SCMs as well. Let him know, what you need. I don't know how easy it is to implement git support.

Comment: svn's good enough. anything to prevent fat finger config loss. (git svn to the rescue!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use git in that directory just like in any other directory.

I doubt there’s a plugin for backing up configuration files on changes to git automatically.