# Save all Jenkins jobs to a repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

I have 15 Jenkins jobs configured in order to implement a specific flow. I am improving and editing these jobs as time goes by.

Is there a way to save all these jobs and its configurations to a repository or at least in the form of export jobs, save it and import when needed?

Comment: Possible duplicat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087142/is-there-a-way-to-keep-hudson-jenkins-configuration-files-in-source-control

Answer (score 3):

There are two plugins that will help you save Jenkins jobs, "SCM Sync configuration" and "JobConfigHistory" defined at the wiki.jenkins-ci.org website.

[SCM Sync Configuration Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) (which keeps the config in a SCM repository)

or

[Job Config History Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) (Saves copies of all job and system configurations)

Answer (score 2):

The [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) allows to define the jobs in a DSL and store the DSL scripts in a SCM repo. The DSL increases the readability of the config files in contrast to the XML format.

For an intro, see the slides and video from the [Configuration as Code: The Job DSL Plugin](https://www.cloudbees.com/jenkins/juc-2015/abstracts/europe/01-01-1500-spilker) talk at the Jenkins User Conference 2015 in London.

Answer (score 0):

You can move/copy jobs to another destination simply by copying directory with job (default path for jobs directories is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs).

You can get more info here - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Comment: Ya I have seen it but I feel it isn't the efficient way of archiving/saving. Is there any other way to link with a repo?

Answer (score 0):

The [Workflow feature](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) may let you write your entire process as one (Groovy) script, which you can then maintain in your version control system alongside other sources.