# How to store Jenkins embeded scripts in a version control system such as Git?

Tags: git, jenkins

My Jenkins server has lot of embedded scripts (not script files) such as Groovy, Shell , Batch etc..

Is there anyway to keep track of the changes doing for these script by submitting the changes to a 'Version control system'

I found this [Job Config History Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin). But it only keep a copy of config file locally.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087142/6128602.

Comment: @luka5z: meet me, I will buy you a beer jug!

Answer (score 0):

The way I achieve this is by running a periodic job that runs a shell script to commits changes. I use this in conjunction with the [thin backup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup), which, similar to the Job Config History plugin, stores the backups locally. I basically let the plugin do all the work of backing up the specified configurations, and then it's a few lines of scripting to commit those backups to the repository.

Note: I use svn rather than Git, otherwise I'd pass along the shell script to do the commits. I believe there are resources out there already though that will give you the commands you need to commit to Git.

Comment: Actually I'm considering this approach also because SCM Sync configuration plugin not easy to configure. I'm still couldn't figure out to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I tried the SCM Sync configuration plugin and couldn't get it to work well for me. Also, the latest release has a fatal bug in it that requires a bit of manual configuration to reverse.